# Standart/common/right way to send data in API request

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I'm trying to learn how to create an API (I use Laravel in the backend and Postman to send requests), but I have a basic doubt when sending data to be processed in the backend.

I see that there are several ways to send data to the backend, but I'm not sure which is the right way to do it.
For example, with Postman I have seen that the sending can be done as parameters through the URI:

> [www.example.com/api/v1/orders?limit=10&offset=20](http://www.example.com/api/v1/orders?limit=10&offset=20)

I can also do it in the body of the request through the tags

- form data
- x-www-form-urlencoded
- raw
- other ...

I understand that I can make the request along with sending data in several ways. I would like to know what should be the correct, standard or optimal way to do it for usual requests such as getting a series of records with a filtering, an order or a pagination.

I would also like to know if the way of sending data should depend on the verb to be used in the request.

My main question/problem is that I would like the way users use the API to be as simple or suitable as possible for them. I'm clear that I want to always return the data (when necessary) in JSON format but I'm not clear on how it should be sent.

Please, could someone clarify these doubts (maybe a link to a page where this kind of doubts are dealt with).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends:

- `GET`, `HEAD` and `DELETE` don't have a request body so all parameters have to be send via URL
- `POST` can be easily sent via form data in Laravel
- For `PUT`/`PATCH` I prefer `application/json` because PHP sends it via `php://input` stream which can have some problems in Laravel sometimes

You can also combine URL parameters and the request body. [Compound types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) (for example models) can only be send as one via request body while it might suffice to send an id via URL parameter.

I guess, nearly more important is the overall format and documentation. The format should be consistent, easy to understand and maybe standardized (for example: https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud).

Keep in mind that forms do two things by default:

- Only having methods `GET` and `POST`
- Only having [`ectype`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` and `text/plain`

If you want to enforce something else, you have to use scripts/libraries to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, it appears that JSON content (for `POST`, `PUT`, and `PATCH`) is the most popular and readable. It is well recognizable and clean. Examples in the documentation are easy to read.

I would go for JSON for both, incoming parameters and the outgoing response. This regards parameters related to the business logic of your application.

At the same time, for `GET`, `HEAD`, and `DELETE` methods, you don't have a payload at all. For parameters related to controlling the API (i.e. not strictly related to the business logic of the application, but to the API itself) I'd go for query parameters. This applies to parameters like `limit`, `offset`, `order_by`, etc.

P.S. There is only one caveat related to the JSON format. If your API happens to have file parameters you may face the problem. You can still use JSON format, but in such a case, you should encode your files (e.g. using `base64`) and put it as string parameters of your JSON. This may be demanding for the consumers of your API ;) This will also enlarge your files and will probably force you to process these files in memory. The alternative is to use `multipart/form-data` as a request `Content-Type` - this way you can have both, the form and separate "space" for files. It's worth keeping this case in mind when you decide.